# Documentation for Adobe AIR client in Worklight?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to find any documentation on the usage of an Adobe AIR client in Worklight.  The only thing I see is how it locates the SDK through an environment variable.

Is there any documentation on Adobe AIR usage?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for in specific? Anything concrete?

Adobe AIR support in Worklight extends to Desktop - Windows.
It creates a container for your web resources and allows for some Worklight API usage, the rest is pure HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

Information pertaining to Adobe Air:

- [Learning Worklight client side API](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/03_01_Learning_Worklight_client_side_API.pdf)
- [General information when developing desktop applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/03_13_General_information_when_developing_desktop_applications.pdf)
- [IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp) (search for "adobe air")

Comment: There isn't:  1) any doc about how to actually do the build, there are additional configuration options in the Air <app>.xml configuration, how can you supply them?, 2) when you "Build and deploy", it doesn't seem to build the .air or exe, is this included or do you have to do it externally?  3) how can you change the compile options (there are many for AIR).  That's a few major ones that I have immediately, I'm sure there will be more once actually doing any work using this option.

Comment: Well, I do suggest that you read the Getting Started training modules because some of your questions Are being addressed there. Like, 1) how to build and 2) where to download (the .exe) from (you download via a link in Worklight Console). As for the <app>.xml configuration file and compile options, yes, it seems this information is not provided in the documentation.

Comment: I assume the "adt" command line is used, any way to modify/customize the command line

Comment: There are no customizations available in regards to building the Adobe AIR application (other than adding a signing certificate). You can submit a feature request for that if you'd like: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25

Comment: @DavidW, is your question resolved based on the above?